# File size not showing in windows explorer

Tags: c#, filesize, file-writing

I am writing lots of files using c#. File size is 1 mb and about 500 files are there in the folder.All the files are written properly with all of their contents. But some files are showing file size zero in windows explorer even though it has contents.

I can see size when I copy the files to other location.
Also I can see size when i open in the same location and refresh the windows explorer.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in windows explorer more then a bug in your program...

Comment: How do you check file has contents when its size is zero?

Comment: @demonplus It's size is not zero, windows explorer displays it's size zero.

Comment: yes like @MehrzadChehraz said its size is not zero

Answer (score 0):

This is propably a caching problem in Windows Explorer. It measured the filesize when your program created the new file, but before any content has been written to it. Now it is showing the wrong (outdated) value.
If you can open the file and see the content, everything worked fine.

Try to refresh the folder in Windows Explorer with <kbd>F5</kbd> or try it again after some time.

You can also open the console (`cmd`), go to your target folder (`cd path`) and take a look at the correct filesize using the command `dir`.

Comment: I refreshed and I am sure about the working of my code -all contents are fine. This is only for user not to be misleaded

Comment: Same situation.  NLog, for example appends to a log file and you can see in Windows Explorer its filesize grow by the second.  Using a BinaryWriter over a FileStream and even calling .Flush on both objects, I don't see a size increase.